# Не удается залогиниться в VS2019 Браузер устарел

Tags: visual-studio-2019, microsoft-edge

Скачал VS2019. Пробный период истек сегодня, появляется диалоговое окно входа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нажимаю "Войти", появляется пустое окно с окном ошибки выполнения скрипта. Нажимал"Да" и "Нет" на результат в итоге не влияет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Окно с ошибкой скрипта появляется еще 2 раза:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Окно логина. Захожу по номеру телефона.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка: Браузер устарел. Пользуюсь последней версией Chrome, специально установил Edge для решения проблемы и перезагрузил компьютер, ошибка осталась.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Прежде чем исправить эту проблему, нужно проверить обновлен ли у вас браузер,который стоит по умолчанию. Если вы удостоверились,что ваша версия актуальна, переходим к следующему пункту. А именно нажимаем на кнопку "Параметры учетной записи"

[image: Прежде чем исправить эту проблему, нужно проверить обновлен ли у вас браузер,который стоит по умолчанию. Если вы удостоверились,что ваша версия актуальна, переходим к следующему пункту. А именно нажимаем на кнопку "Параметры учетной записи".]

Вас перекинет в параметры, где будет учетная запись, там будет написано "Встроенный веб-браузер"
[image: Вас перекинет в параметры, где будет учетная запись, там будет написано "Встроенный веб-браузер".]

Нажимаем на нижнюю стрелку.

[image: Нажимаем на нижнюю стрелку]

Меняем "Встроенный веб-браузер" на "Системный веб-браузер"
[image: Меняем "Встроенный веб-браузер" на "Системный веб-браузер"]

После этого нажимаете "ОК", а дальше нажимаете войти и вас перекинет в браузер и вы можете спокойно авторизоваться.